# hibernate selecting sum of few Entity fields

Tags: sql, hibernate, select, playframework-2.2

I am trying to get from db only a few columns sum. I dont wonna download whole record (entity) but only few columns from whole table. And I dont wanna many records of them. I just one to have a sum.
I have something like that:

```
TypedQuery sumsOfSharedMeters = (TypedQuery) JPA
    .em()
    .createNativeQuery(
        "SELECT "
        + " SUM(wszysUruchProc), SUM(wszysProcToku), SUM(wszysWykoProc), SUM(wszysPrzeterProc), "
        + " SUM(wszysPowtPrzeterProc), SUM(zgloszNiezgodDoRejNiezgod), SUM(niezgodWykryteAudWew), SUM(l4), SUM(nz) "
        + " FROM ZycieBiuro_WorkerMonthReport E WHERE year=:year "
        + " AND intmonth=:month ")
            .setParameter("year", year)
            .setParameter("month", month);
Object results = sumsOfSharedMeters.getSingleResult();
```

But I am getting an object wich is an:
Ljava.lang.Object;@621aba

but no usefull data.
Please help